# Magellan in Foundation - prevent add "top" style to element

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

In default, Magellan (Sticky navigation's plugin in Foundation) adds to element "top" property. I want prevent it, because I've also fixed topbar, so navigation is underneath. My navigation show is animated and all properties are added by CSS, so I just need prevent add `top: 0px` directly inline div.

My code looks that:

```
<div class="sticky bar" data-magellan-expedition="fixed">...</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.sticky.bar.fixed {
   bottom: auto;
   padding-bottom: 6px;
   z-index: 98;
   top:45px;
   animation:subnav_sticky .2s;
   -webkit-animation:subnav_sticky .2s;
}

@keyframes subnav_sticky
{
   from {top:-33px;}
   to {top:45px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes subnav_sticky /* Safari and Chrome */
{
   from {top:-33px;}
   to {top:45px;}
}
```

It's possible without edit JavaScript plugin?

Comment: Add `!important` to the `top` value you set in your css. This will ensure the inline styling being applied does not override the desired style.

Comment: I tried it and works, but in Firefox causes broke animation.

Comment: Is your problem the top property for two top-navigators?

Comment: My problem is `top: 0px` in navigation because Magellan Plugin adds it inline element.

Comment: correct, but what you need exactly? could you explain it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something.

[joseluisq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20935797/1766316)'s answer with Javascript is great. I can't add !important into CSS, because it broke animation in Firefox. But I found a solution on [Foundation GitHub repository](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1763). Nobody adds it into documentation...

The solution is just add `data-magellan-top-offset` into element. So in my problem it will be:

```
<div class="sticky bar" data-magellan-expedition="fixed" data-magellan-top-offset="45">...</div>
```

I hope it will be helpful ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Foundation 5 but there's a fix on the way: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/4841-magellan-top-offsetgone

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see you want to rewrite top property for Magellan, Magellan adds the top property value via javascript, so you can try to rewrite this property using `!important` in your css for your other top navigator.
The other solution is using javascript for replace the top value as you need:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $('div[data-magellan-expedition=fixed]').css('top', 'your top value');
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, hope it helps someone.

You can configure magellan in javascript using something like this as explained in Foundation's [website](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html#js)

```
$(document).foundation({
"magellan-expedition": {
  active_class: 'active', // specify the class used for active sections
  threshold: 0, // how many pixels until the magellan bar sticks, 0 = auto
  destination_threshold: 20, // pixels from the top of destination for it to be considered active
  throttle_delay: 50, // calculation throttling to increase framerate
  fixed_top: 0, // top distance in pixels assigend to the fixed element on scroll
  offset_by_height: true // whether to offset the destination by the expedition height. Usually you want this to be true, unless your expedition is on the side.
}
});
```

the field named 'fixed_top' in there is the one that defines the top distance of the nav element. Make sure that's set to 0 and it should work. 
Note that this should be loaded last to make sure it doesn't get overwritten.